# How to search a column name from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a huge database with so many tables and tables are having so many columns.

My DB is MySQL and I have to search for a particular column.

Is there a way available in MySQL to search a column name from all tables in a database?

Comment: If you need to search a column name then your table design is most probably wrong. Can you change it and if so, do you need a hint how to?

Comment: I swear, i havent created the DB Mr @juergend

Comment: @lad2025 - I have so many tables in my db and i have to search for a particular column and its really hard to go to every table and check the column. If it was easy, i didnt have posted my question here :)

Comment: Did I say it was easy/hard. Do not take it personal. Question is question, it is obvious duplicate. If you think that I am wrong you could cast reopen vote or add question http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @lad2025 I appreciate you replied and seriously I havent taken it personally, I was just trying to explain my situation. No hard feeling.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Retrieve it from **[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-columns-table.html)**

**Query**

```
select table_name, column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name like '%search_keyword%'; -- change search_keyword accordingly
```

Or if you want to search for exact column name then no need of `LIKE`.

```
where column_name = 'column_name_to_be_find';
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @Ullas but I have so many tables in my db and i have to search for a particular column and its really hard to go to every table and check the column name.

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma : You don't need to go for each table to search for the column name.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```